# Excel date format transposing numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, date-format

How to stop excel changing date format?

I type in 05/11/2014 as in fifth November and it displays 11 May 2014 in the cell

Yet in the cell content line at the top of the sheet it still displays 05/11/2014.

**EDIT**

I have chosen dd/mmm/yyyy cell format from the cellformat menu. And indeed it is displaying day month year. but it is not displaying the day month year I enter.

Comment: Go to Control Panel -> Region and Language. Make sure it is set to the correct (desired) format

Answer (score 2):

Could it be you're in a different locale? According to [the official MS-Office Excel-2007 help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/enter-data-manually-in-worksheet-cells-HP001216364.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP010054141) the control panel "Regional And Language Settings" should help you set it. Otherwise you'll need to clarify the problem and/or read more of that help-file.

Or, it could be a problem with the spreadsheet? Look at this HowTo to change the format inside a single document or even cell. [wikihow:Change Date Format In Excel](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Date-Formats-in-Microsoft-Excel)
Basically: click the cell, row, column .. whatever, hit the format option, select "date" and then the format you'd like.

[image]